# Syntax error in Less doesn't make sense

Tags: compiler-errors, less, syntax-error

I'm trying to compile a less file to CSS using lessc (installed by npm).

```
SyntaxError: Operation on an invalid type in /home/..../static/less/app.less:null:-1
1
```

Note that the first line is not cut off. The 1 from line two is clearly after a line break, so how am I getting a null:-1? It seems like that is a line reference that proceeds the file. Is this from an include? (I've got two) if so, what does the 1 on the second line mean?

I'm using lessc v1.3.3 installed via NPM on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would help to have a little more info. What version of Less.js are you using? If you're using 1.4.0-beta then try doing either `--strict-maths-off` or `--strict-units-off`, or both. There are other 3rd part compilers that simplify things a bit too.

Comment: sorry for the late response, but yes. As it turns out, you don't always get the same error messages when you compile to console vs. compiling to file (or at least I didn't). Either way, it was a math issue.

Comment: glad you got it figured out either way